# First full title, then short title in \autocite: biblatex-chicago authordate with entrysubtype={classical}

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I'm citing some classical authors using biblatex-chicago (authordate format) and the entrysubtype={classical} in my bib-file. Calling \autocite now suppresses the year and adds the title of the work in question instead.

With those sources using the classical entrysubtype, I would like to use the full title in the first quotation, and thereafter use the title given in "shorttitle". At the moment, it seems to me that once there is a shorttitle included in the bib-record, the full title is ignored when calling \autocite. Any subsequent uses of \autocite drop the title altogether and only print page/section numbers.

Is there any chance to get \autocite use the full title in the first citation, but print the short title in addition to the page/section numbers in subsequent citations?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[authordate,strict,backend=bibtex8,citetracker=true,babel=other,%
bibencoding=inputenc,sorting=nyt]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibsample.bib}
@BOOK{Plato2003,
  title = {The Republic},
  publisher = {Penguin},
  year = {2003},
  author = {Plato},
  address = {London},
  nameb = {Lee, Desmond},
  entrysubtype = {classical},
  shorttitle = {Rep.},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bibsample.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite[123d]{Plato2003}
\autocite[344a]{Plato2003}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

What happens at the moment is:

the first instance of `\autocite[123a]{Plato2003}` now results in (Plato *Rep.* 123a)
and subsequent `\autocite[345a]{{Plato2003}` drop both author and title, producing (345a).

What I would like to get:

The first `\autocite` to produce (Plato *The Republic* 123a) (= using the full title) while
subsequent `\autocite` would use the short title and section number without author: (*Rep.* 123b)

If a bib-record does not have a shorttitle nor entrysubtype={classical}, then I would like \autocite to act in the default way: (author year, pagenumber) first and subsequently (pagenumber).

Any help is greatly appreciated..!

Comment: Your question title (and the linked question) is about modifying the result of *first* citations, while your question body is about modifying *all* citations done with `\autocite`. Please edit your question and clarify your requirements.

Comment: @lockstep: thank you for your comment, you are quite right about that. I have tried to rephrase both the question body and title, hopefully that helped.

Comment: Which title (full or short) should be used for follow-up citations usings `\autocite` (the non-starred version)?

Comment: My idea was to use \autocite for first citations and \autocite* for follow-up citations, mainly because using \autocite for follow-ups drops the title altogether (which I don't want either), while \autocite* does everything it should. So my question then does not really refer to follow-up citations, but primarily hopes to change the behaviour of \autocite while leaving \autocite* the way it currently is... does that make sense?

Comment: That's a bad idea -- imagine that you restructure your text (shifting some `\section`s) and what used to be a first citation is now a follow-up. I suggest to rewrite your question and specify the requirements (for first as well as for follow-up citations, possibly for different entry types) for a single citation command (`\autocite`).

Comment: That's true, I just thought this clumsy way would perhaps be an easier way of solving it. But I guess it probably really is wiser to alter the first/subsequent behaviour of \autocite, which is why I've edited by question once again..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the desired output for the first citation, you can copy the contents of the `title` field into `labeltitle`.

In the second citation you need to suppress both ibidem citation labels and (in non-ibdiem labels) the `labelname` name list. `biblatex-chicago` does the former by issuing `\blx@ibidreset`. The latter can be done by clearing `labelname`.

The following hook puts this all together. Note that it is executed at every citation command, not just `\autocite`.

```
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}}
               and not test {\iffieldundef{shorttitle}} }
    {\ifciteseen
       {\blx@ibidreset\clearname{labelname}}
       {\savefield{title}{\cbxtitle}\restorefield{labeltitle}{\cbxtitle}}}
    {}}
\makeatother
```

Just add this to your preamble. It should work with the latest `biblatex-chicago` release, which requires biber for the author-date styles.

Comment: Massive thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Irene No problem. It is more efficient to modify the relevant bibliography macros, but I was too lazy to sort all that source code out.